# Passing PageParameters From WicketPanel

Tags: java, image, wicket, panel, mount

How could I use PageParameters on a Wicketpanel? 
I'm willing to load images from filesystem on a WicketPanel, and I found a tutorial for that, but they are using a Page, and in my case, I want to mount the images on a Panel. What should I change in this class or do I HAVE to implement a PageClass for this usecase?
http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/
https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/blob/master/request-mappers/src/main/java/com/wicketinaction/requestmappers/resources/images/ImageResourcesPage.java

```
public class ImageResourcesPage extends WebPage {

    /**
     * The image names for which dynamic images will be generated
     */
    private static final String[] IMAGE_NAMES = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};

    public ImageResourcesPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        final ResourceReference imagesResourceReference = new ImageResourceReference();
        final PageParameters imageParameters = new PageParameters();

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>("list", Arrays.asList(IMAGE_NAMES)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
                String imageName = item.getModelObject();
                imageParameters.set("name", imageName);

                // generates nice looking url (the mounted one) to the current image
                CharSequence urlForWordAsImage = getRequestCycle().urlFor(imagesResourceReference, imageParameters);
                ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("link", urlForWordAsImage.toString());
                link.setBody(Model.of(imageName));
                item.add(link);

            }
        };
        add(listView);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Am I getting it right that you wish to get the current page parameters from a Panel?

Comment: I want to mount an image on a Panel, that is on another panel mounted, and all of them are mounted on a page. 
But in the tutorial of wicketinaction, in the link I posted, they tell  to mount an image on a page, I should implement a class (ImageReferencePage) that extends "WebPage". But in my case I want to mount the image on a panel not directly on the page. How should I do that? How can I adabt that class to my case (with panel)? Should I get the pageparameters through the panel or what? Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  I Had just to add the IModel as argument in the ImageResourcePanel-Constructor.

`public class ImageResourcesPanel extends Panel {

```
/**
 * The image names for which dynamic images will be generated
 */
private static final String[] IMAGE_NAMES = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};

public ImageResourcesPanel(final String wicketId, IModel<Book> book) {
    super(wicketId, book);

     int refNumber = book.getModelObject().getRefNumber();


    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>("list", Arrays.asList(IMAGE_NAMES)) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {

            String imageName = item.getModelObject();
            imageParameters.set("name", imageName);
            imageParameters.set("ref_number", refNumber);

    final ResourceReference imagesResourceReference = new ImageResourceReference();
    final PageParameters imageParameters = new PageParameters();

            // generates nice looking url (the mounted one) to the current image
            CharSequence urlForWordAsImage = getRequestCycle().urlFor(imagesResourceReference, imageParameters);
            ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("link", urlForWordAsImage.toString());
            link.setBody(Model.of(imageName));
            item.add(link);

        }
    };
    add(listView);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

The example code shown does not actually use the `pageParameters` from the `WebPage` in the image handling at all, but has an additional `PageParameters imageParameters` field for the images.  There's no reason you can't do the same in a `Panel`.

Something along the lines of

```
public class ImageResourcesPanel extends Panel {

    /**
     * The image names for which dynamic images will be generated
     */
    private static final String[] IMAGE_NAMES = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};

    public ImageResourcesPanel(final String wicketId) {
        super(wicketId);

        final ResourceReference imagesResourceReference = new ImageResourceReference();
        final PageParameters imageParameters = new PageParameters();

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>("list", Arrays.asList(IMAGE_NAMES)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
                String imageName = item.getModelObject();
                imageParameters.set("name", imageName);

                // generates nice looking url (the mounted one) to the current image
                CharSequence urlForWordAsImage = getRequestCycle().urlFor(imagesResourceReference, imageParameters);
                ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("link", urlForWordAsImage.toString());
                link.setBody(Model.of(imageName));
                item.add(link);

            }
        };
        add(listView);
    }

}
```

should work just as well as the page version shown.

I'm not sure final fields for `imageParameters` and `imageResourceReference` are appropriate though.  I would probably just make them local variables within the `populateItem(ListItem<String> item)` method.

**Update based on comments:**

It appears this example produces links to images and what you want is embedded images.  A better starting point for that might be the [images example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/images/) in the wicket-library examples page.  The 
`ImageResourceReference` code from this example might however still be useful in conjunction with the other example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I Think that is what I need here. But where should I give the path where my images are? instead of the IMAGE_NAMES ("one", "two" & "three")?

Comment: If the images are not constant as in the example code, you could make a method that gets them from somewhere else (e.g., from a database).  This method could either be called from this panel or the result of the method (an array of Strings) could be passed in as an additional argument to the panel's constructor.

Comment: much better with your answers.. but I'm not really done! I wanted to try with a jpg file now, but I have 2 problems: 1) I'm getting the link displayed on the panel, and not the image, 2) when I click on it, it getting me to a white page and i'm not getting the image displayed at least on that page. I tried 
`private static final String[] IMAGE_NAMES = new String[] {"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg"};`
and it is changed on the browser address tab to: `THE_PATH_GIVEN_IN_THE_MOUNT_RESOURCE_METHOD/**C:%5CUsers%5CPublic%5CPictures%5CSample%20Pictures%5CDesert.jpg**`

Comment: and this is what I'm getting displayed as Link: 
`C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg`

Comment: but could I make such embedded images? in that link, there isnt any code examples.. just images are displayed..

Comment: There's a link labeled "Source Code" near the top right of the page, which will open a popup window with the source.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just hand over the page parametersfrom the Panel/Page you embed it in?
Alternatively you can use

```
RequestCycle.get().getPageParameters()
```

but I think handing it over from the embedding component would be cleaner.